# MySQL : Query to return some columns + concat column values from same table

Tags: mysql

I have TableContacts :

```
ID Gender Person PhoneNumber
1  Male   Jhon   500000001
2  Male   Jhon   500000002
3  Male   Sam    500000003
4  Male   Sam    500000009
```

I would Select Gender, Person where ID = 1 and concatenate All John Phone Numbers in the same field like that :

```
Gender Person PhoneNumbrSSS
Male   John   500000001, 50000002
```

Thanks

Comment: I can see no correlation between the data set and the result set

Comment: first, select one row (id = ) from the table, than concatenate person phone  numbers based on Person column already selected in the first part.

Comment: Why is 500000003 included in the output number does not belong to John AND there are no John in your source (presumably Jhon is a typo?)

Comment: Sory, output is : Gender Person PhoneNumbrSSS
Male   John   500000001, 50000002

Comment: @ElyesZ please **edit and update your question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a query to return the `Person` with `id = 1` and then with `group_concat()` get the Person's phone numbers:

```
select Gender, Person, 
  group_concat(PhoneNumber) PhoneNumbrSSS
from TableContacts
where Person = (select Person from TableContacts where id = 1)
group by Gender, Person
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pCcUG3gcY9ZtKwvK7maR3o/0).
Results:

```
| Gender | Person | PhoneNumbrSSS       |
| ------ | ------ | ------------------- |
| Male   | Jhon   | 500000001,500000002 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT function

```
SELECT Gender, Person, GROUP_CONCAT(PhoneNumber)
as "Phonenumber"  
from employee
where id=1
group by Gender, Person;
```

Comment: i must select by  ID = 1 (first, select one row (id = ) from the table, than concatenate person phone numbers based on Person column already selected in the first part).

Comment: i tested with : <br>SELECT (SELECT Person FROM Table WHERE ID = '1'), (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `PhoneNumber` SEPARATOR ',' )  FROM Table WHERE Person = 'Jhon') , Here, two problems : ProbleOne : i can select only one column Person) ProblemTwo : Jhon the person is static, must be variable from Person column)

Comment: now you have all the data you can filter by id which you want using where clause SELECT Gender, Person, GROUP_CONCAT(PhoneNumber)
as "Phonenumber"  
from employee                                                                                                where id=1
group by Gender, Person;

Comment: not the result that i would to return, i must select gender, person, other.. from table where id = x, than i must select concat the phne numbers of  the only person that i already selcted ( person that the id = x).

Comment: must return 1 row :

Comment: Gender Person PhoneNumbrSSS
Male   John   500000001, 50000002, 500000003

Comment: So you want to concat phonenumber from all rows but Gender and Person will be only from first row.

Comment: select person, his gender, (maybe other columns), where ID = x, and concat his phone numbers from the same table

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT a.Gender, a.Person, GROUP_CONCAT(a.PhoneNumber)
as "Phonenumber"  
from employee a inner join employee b
on a.Person = b.Person
where a.id=1
group by a.Gender, a.Person;
```

Comment: Please define what "this" is. Explain what you fixed and why you did it that way.